# Updating the profile in laravel 10 + inertia, validation error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm working with Laravel 10 + inertiajs.I want to update my profile, but when I enter the information, it gives an error message saying that the "Name" and "Email" fields are required, even though I am not leaving those fields empty. I fill in all the required fields, but it still shows the error message. However, if I update the profile without adding a profile picture, there is no issue. The problem occurs when I add the profile picture field.

this is my controller code.

```
 public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->user()->fill($request->validated());
        if ($request->user()->isDirty('email')) {
            $request->user()->email_verified_at = null;
        }
        if ($request->hasFile('profile_picture')) {
            $file = $request->file('profile_picture');
            $filename = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->storeAs('profile_pictures', $filename); 
            $request->user()->profile_picture = $filename;
        }
        $request->user()->save();
        return Redirect::route('profile.edit');
    }
```

this is my componenet.

```
<script setup>
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError.vue';
import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel.vue';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import TextInput from '@/Components/TextInput.vue';
import { Link, useForm, usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

defineProps({
    mustVerifyEmail: {
        type: Boolean,
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
    },
});

const user = usePage().props.auth.user;

const form = useForm({
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    profile_picture: user.profile_picture,

});
</script>

<template>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h2 class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">اطلاعات پروفایل</h2>

            <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
                به روزرسانی اطلاعات پروفایل و آدرس ایمیل حساب خود را انجام دهید.
            </p>
        </header>

        <form @submit.prevent="form.patch(route('profile.update'))" class="mt-6 space-y-4" >

            <div>
                <InputLabel for="name" value="نام" />

                <TextInput
                    id="name"
                    type="text"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    v-model="form.name"
                    required
                    autofocus
                    autocomplete="name"
                />
                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.name" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <InputLabel for="email" value="ایمیل" />
                <TextInput
                    id="email"
                    type="email"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    v-model="form.email"
                    required
                    autocomplete="username"
                />
                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.email" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="avatar">عکس</label>
                <TextInput type="file" @input="form.profile_picture = $event.target.files[0]" />
                <progress v-if="form.progress" :value="form.progress.percentage" max="100">
                {{ form.progress.percentage }}%
                </progress>
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                <PrimaryButton :disabled="form.processing">ذخیره</PrimaryButton>

                <Transition
                    enter-active-class="transition ease-in-out"
                    enter-from-class="opacity-0"
                    leave-active-class="transition ease-in-out"
                    leave-to-class="opacity-0"
                >
                    <p v-if="form.recentlySuccessful" class="text-sm text-gray-600">ذخیره شد.</p>
                </Transition>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</template>
```

this is my ProfileUpdateRequest

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'string', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore(Auth::user())],
        'password' => ['nullable', 'string', 'confirmed', 'min:8'],
        'profile_picture' => ['required'],

    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `ProfileUpdateRequest` ?

Comment: '    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'string', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore(Auth::user())],
            'password' => ['nullable', 'string', 'confirmed', 'min:8'],
            'profile_picture' => ['required'],

        ];
    }'

Comment: edit your question with that code please

Comment: added my ProfileUpdateRequest

Comment: verify the data of `form.data`. You can do that using a `add` before the form submit

Comment: first i would check the fields submitted are ok by inspecting the request with dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Please [read the documentation about file uploads](https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads) for inertia. Note that at the very bottom, it says that file uploads using the `patch` method are not natively supported.

The work around is to change the signature to `.post` by adding a `PATCH` method input field:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

Or handle the POST yourself and insert it into the JS:

```js
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const form = useForm({
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    profile_picture: user.profile_picture,
    _method: 'patch' // shim the patch hack here
});

router.post(route('profile.update'), form);
```